# oSX 10.8.2 checking for gcc wrong location

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm having an issue with Apache ab and I'm trying to update it with a newer version.

When running ./configure on the apache download there is an error on this line

```
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
```

That location does not exist, instead it is in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
```

How can I change it to look in the correct location?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mountainlion apr compile lacking 'cc'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240289/mountainlion-apr-compile-lacking-cc)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to build tk.

I was able to get make to run by creating a symlink from OSX10.8.xctoolchain to XcodeDefault.xctoolchain. This is done easily with the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain
```

This should also solve the problem if it is looking in the wrong location, as it will be redirected to the correct one.